# What is the origin of "Jesus H Christ"?

Tags: phrase

I have always wondered how this meme started.

Comment: This question is probably off topic here, but at any rate, it has already been answered elsewhere. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25716/who-is-jesus-h-christ

Comment: How is a name of jesus off topic on a site dedicated to christianity?

Comment: The same way asking about the origin of phrases like "Hot d*mn," "Gosh," and "Golly-Gee" would be off topic. That is a language discussion, and really has nothing (or at best, very little) to do with Christianity.

Comment: I don't believe language and christianity to be mutually exclusive

Comment: Certainly not, but on SE sites, when there is an overlap, the one with the closer association with the question is usually the more appropriate place to ask it.  Now if your question was "Is the name Jesus H Christ found in the Bible?" then this would be the better site for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact origin is unknown because it seems to have originated from slang. In the Autobiography of Mark Twain, Mark mentions that Jesus H Christ had old origins that were unknown.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be that on the Eucharist, in some depictions, [the letters IHS are spelled.](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07649a.htm)

Comment: This really is the best guess I've seen.  The letters are used [other places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christogram) as well.